# Passing argument 4 of 'draw_character' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

I keep getting the warnings:

**In function 'main':**
passing argument 4 of 'draw_character' makes pointer from integer without a cast
[Note] expected 'char ** (*)[7]' but argument is of type 'char'

but I don't know how to fix these. I would really appreciate your answers :)
Here's my program.

```
int draw_character(int ASCII_Value,int font,int height,char **output_matrix[7][7]);
void print_character(char **output_matrix);

int main(){

char **output_matrix[10][10];
int ASCII_Value = 0,  height = 0;

    printf("DRAW CHARACTER");
    printf("\n\nEnter ASCII Value of the character : ");
    scanf("%d", &ASCII_Value);
    printf("FONT (1 - default or 2 - special): ");
    scanf("%d", &font);
    printf("Height: ");
    scanf("%d", &height);
    draw_character(ASCII_Value, font, height, **output_matrix[7][7]);

return 0;
}

int draw_character(int ASCII_Value,int font,int height,char **output_matrix[7][7]){

int rowsize;

if(font == 1)
{
    height = 5;
    rowsize = 6;
    switch(ASCII_Value)
    {
    case 65:
    case 97:
    strncpy(**output_matrix[0]," *  * ",6);
    strncpy(**output_matrix[1]," *   *",6);
    strncpy(**output_matrix[2],"******",6);
    strncpy(**output_matrix[3],"*     *",6);
    strncpy(**output_matrix[4],"*     *",6);
    print_character(**output_matrix);
    break;

    /*Print B*/
    case 66:
    case 98:
    strncpy(**output_matrix[0],"******",6);
    strncpy(**output_matrix[1],"*    *",6);
    strncpy(**output_matrix[2],"******",6);
    strncpy(**output_matrix[3],"*    *",6);
    strncpy(**output_matrix[4],"******",6);
    print_character(**output_matrix);
    break;

    /*Print C*/
    case 67:
    strncpy(**output_matrix[0]," *****",6);
    strncpy(**output_matrix[1],"*     ",6);
    strncpy(**output_matrix[2],"*     ",6);
    strncpy(**output_matrix[3],"*     ",6);
    strncpy(**output_matrix[4]," *****",6);
    print_character(**output_matrix);
    break;
}
}
return 0;
            }


void print_character(char **output_matrix){
            printf(" %c", &output_matrix);


}
```

Comment: Try `draw_character(ASCII_Value, font, height, output_matrix);`

Comment: Yeah... you have stars in your eyes..

Answer (score 1):

You are dereferencing pointer to pointer in

```
char **output_matrix[10][10];
draw_character(ASCII_Value, font, height, **output_matrix[7][7]);
```

Instead, pass array:

```
draw_character(ASCII_Value, font, height, output_matrix);
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I have one more question, what should I do to print the values inside the 2d array? :)

Comment: char **arr[row][col]; initalize(arr, row, col); (check errors); for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            **arri][j] = '.';
            printf("%c ", **arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }